# Библиотека для "плавных" переходов

Tags: анимация, javascript

Как-то так это будет правильней назвать. Я ищу js библиотеку для осуществления анимаций с DOM, вот таких [вот](https://dribbble.com/shots/1514896-On-the-clock-animation). Кто делал подобное - подскажите, что использовали

Answer (score 1):

какого рода анимацию вы ищете ? может просто всем каким надо элементам добавьте класс animate

> .animate{  -webkit-transition: all
> .7s;  -moz-transition: all .7s; 
> -o-transition: all .7s;  transition: all .7s; }

либо тогда jQuery.animate()

Comment: в указанной ссылке - пример